# I am using 10 executors but only half of them i.e 5 are processing tasks

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In my spark cluster I'm using 10 executors on 3 nodes, 6 on 1, 2-2 on other 2 nodes but only half on each machine are being used by Spark to process the data.

Don't know what is the issue.

Comment: How many partitions your data contain?

Comment: I'm using 4 partitions, but no. of executors working are 5 or less.

Comment: Well that's your problem. Each partition can be handled by 1 executor. you can try repartitioning your data